# Vuex state not updating data

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuex, vue-sfc

I am using Vuex with axios to fetch data from my backend. But somehow the state property `userName` is not updating in my Vue Single File Component(SFC).

**approot.js**
**state**

```
const state = {    
    userName: 'foo' 
};
```

**getter**

```
const getters = {
    getUserName: (state) => state.userName    
};
```

**Single File Component**

```
<template>
  <div id="navbar">
    //cut for brievity          
    <span>{{getUserName}}</span>                          
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'navbar',
  computed: mapGetters(['getNumberOfJobMessages','getUserName']),
  //cut for brievity

}
</script>

<style scoped>
    //cut for brievity
</style>
```

**Action fetching data with axios from the backend**

```
const actions = {
   async fetchMenuData({ commit }) {
      //fetch data from api controller
      const response = await axios.get('../api/Menu/GetMenu');

      console.log(response.data.userName); //not undefined        
      commit('setMenuData', response.data);
   }
}
```

**Mutation setting state variables**

```
const mutations = {
    setMenuData(state, menuData) {        
       console.log(menuData.userName); //not undefined
       state.userName = menuData.userName;
       console.log(state.userName); //not undefined
    }
}
```

**Problem**
When my single file component calls getUserName it always renders 'foo', the hardcoded value. Im quite baffled by this, since the rest of my state variables are set with the same pattern, and my components have no problems getting them.

Anyone who knows whats going wrong or can see a flaw in my code? It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `fetchMenuData` was not dispatched ?

Comment: And if you didn't, you should dispatch `fetchMenuData` in your component `beforeMount` lifecycle like this, `async beforeMount() {await this.$store.dispatch('fetchMenuData')}`

Comment: hey, pass `response.data.userName` on commit, and change setting option. `setMenuData(state, userName) {        
   state.userName = userName;
}`

Comment: @hasan05 he is already getting it with `menuData.userName` in `setMenuData`mutation

Comment: Oh wait, why did you define `setMenuData` as an action ?

Comment: @AhmetZeybek it is dispatched from another component in it's created() hook.

Comment: @AhmetZeybek, im sorry i was unclear in my post. `setMenuData` is declared as a mutation. Corrected my post.

Answer (score 0):

Use mutations to only set data. and other things do on action. like:

Action:

```
const actions = {
   async fetchMenuData({ commit }) {
      const response = await axios.get('../api/Menu/GetMenu');
      let userName = response.data.userName;
      commit('setUserName', userName);
   }
}
```

And mutations:

```
const mutations = {
    setUserName(state, userName) {        
       state.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Dont forget to dispatch the function `fetchMenuData`

Properly not sure, why this happens. But, I faced this problem and solved by this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 axios.get('../api/Menu/GetMenu')
  .then(({ data }) => {
    commit('setUserName', data.userName);
  }).catch(error => {    })
```

It is better to make a commit in then()